# How to enable verbose or debug on SVN checkout SSH

Tags: svn, ssh, svn-ssh

I'm running an `svn co svn+ssh://` to checkout a large repository. It appears to be hanging for a long time without any feedback.

```
svn co svn+ssh://example.com/test test
```

How can I enable a verbose or debug mode for svn + ssh?

Answer (score 2):

Exporting a `SVN_SSH` variable to `ssh -v`

```
export SVN_SSH="ssh -v "
```

will display verbose debug info on a `svn+ssh://` checkout:

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to example.com port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
...
```

Credit: [halkeye.net](https://www.halkeye.net/2010/07/09/debugging-sshsvn/)